# linux-header 3.2.0-61 archive fail

Tags: 12.04

```
thomas@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
[sudo] password for thomas: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-3.2.0-61 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
thomas@ubuntu:~$
```

This is what I get whenever I try to do anything inside of the terminal, open the software center, or even the update manager.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
`sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: In response to sudo apt-get update. I get a lot of failed to fetch or not found. For the sudo apt-get dist-upgrade it wont run due to the failure stated, and I have a few duplicate source fails. In regards to the sudo apt-get -f install it says the error stated above.

Comment: If you get errors on `sudo apt-get update` please edit the output in your post.

Comment: I can't change it to sudo apt-get update because it has too many links.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update > output` then `nano output` and copy the text.

Comment: There are 196 lines once I type in nano output and they have links in them and I cannot post more than two links under ten reputation.

Comment: On `sudo apt-get update` do all of them fail or just some? Are you sure your internet connection is working (`ping 8.8.8.8`)?

Comment: Just some of them fail, but my Internet is working,

Comment: Try [this](http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/01/restore-your-sources-list-to-defaults.html) to replace the sources list. Also you can open disk utility and run a smart test on your drive it will check for bad sectors, which can cause Problems to.